# Microsoft Entra ID app authentication and Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-devops-rest-api, microsoft-entra-id

I'm working on a multitenant service that would will list, create and update work item in Azure DevOps on behalf of user. I got a bit confused with the setup of Entra ID app, its authentication flow and the Azure DevOps REST API.

I have been googling around, what I come across so far mostly are either using Azure DevOps OAuth 2.0 or using PAT, which I don't want to use PAT, and Microsoft suggest using Entra ID OAuth instead, or are not multitenant solution that accept personal account.

What am I missing for my Entra ID app configuration, or am I misunderstood how the OAuth flow for this works. Any pointer to documentation or code sample would be appreciated.

This is what I have tried:

**Entra ID (Azure AD) app**

Since this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#available-oauth-models) recommend new developer Microsoft Entra ID OAuth instead of the Azure DevOps OAuth 2.0.

- Created Entra ID app with the *Authentication* set to **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)**.
- For *API Permission*, I have `offline_access`, `openid` (from Microsoft Graph), and `vso.work_full` (from the Azure DevOps).
- Web redirect URI set to https://jwt.ms for now.

**Authentication flow**

- Redirect to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<clientId>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&response_mode=query&scope=openid offline_access&prompt=select_account`

After I signed in with my Microsoft account, I get `error=invalid_scope&error_description=The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope 'openid offline_access vso.work_full' does not exist.`

If I use the scope `openid offline_access` then I can get the code, but upon posting the code to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` with `vso.work_full`, I get the same error saying the scope does not exists. I haven't try to authorise without the `openid` and `offline_access` as I want to support personal account, removing those will not allow me to login as personal account.

Answer (score 0):

In the post, you mention wanting to use the `vso.work_full` scope, but in the authentication flow you are not requesting said scope, only `openid` and `offline_access`

It should be something like this:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<clientId>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&response_mode=query&scope=openid offline_access vso.work_full&prompt=select_account`